# Typescript: Map with keys being the same type as values without restricting type of keys

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics

Is there a way to make to following typecheck?

```
const map = new Map()

map.set('stringkey', 'stringvalue') // OK
map.set(5, 10) // OK
const objectKey = { name: 'bob' }
map.set(objectKey, { name: 'alice' }) // OK

const stringValue: string = map.get('stringkey') // OK, but is typed as 'any'
const objectValue: { name: string } = map.get(objectKey) // OK, but is typed as 'any'

map.set('string', 5) // Error
map.set({ name: 'bob' }, { food: 'cake' }) // Error
```

Using the default

```
const map = new Map<any, any>()
```

works but doesn't give helpful types when accessing values as they are all typed as any.

Comment: While modern JS implement a Map which can accept an object as a key, it may not behave the way you seem to be expecting.    When the key is anything except a string or a number, keys are compared by identity, not value.   In other words, keys will be compared with the `===`  operator, and two objects with the same keys and values are not necessarily `===` to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is interesting.  I think the best way for you to proceed is to declare your own interface which represents your particular variation of `Map`:

```
interface SameKeyValueMap {
  clear(): void;
  delete(key: any): boolean;
  forEach(
    callbackfn: <T>(value: T, key: T, map: SameKeyValueMap) => void, thisArg?: any
  ): void;
  get<T>(key: T): T | undefined;
  has(key: any): boolean;
  set<T>(key: T, value: T): this;
  readonly size: number;
}

const map: SameKeyValueMap = new Map();
```

This *mostly* works the way you want:

```
map.forEach((x, y) => (console.log(x === y))); // OK
map.set('stringkey', 'stringvalue') // OK
map.set(5, 10) // OK
const objectKey = { name: 'bob' }
map.set(objectKey, { name: 'alice' }) // OK
```

The following has to be changed because `get()` can return `undefined`:

```
const stringValue: string | undefined = map.get('stringkey')
const objectValue: { name: string } | undefined = map.get(objectKey)
```

And here's the error you want:

```
map.set('string', 5) // Error
```

But the following is not an error:

```
map.set({ name: 'bob' }, { food: 'cake' }) // accepted?
```

If you look, that's because the type `T` is inferred to be `{name: string, food?: undefined} | {name?: undefined, food: string}`.  And that *is* consistent with the values you passed in.  Type inference is a bit of a black art that way.

One way to try to deal with that is to change the `set()` signature to [lower the priority](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) of one of the inference sites for `T`.  This way `T` will only be inferred from one of the parameters, and not both.  Like this:

```
interface SameKeyValueMap {
  clear(): void;
  delete(key: any): boolean;
  forEach(
    callbackfn: <T>(value: T, key: T, map: SameKeyValueMap) => void, thisArg?: any
  ): void;
  get<T>(key: T): T | undefined;
  has(key: any): boolean;
  set<T>(key: T, value: T & {}): this; // lowered priority of value
  readonly size: number;
}
```

That seems to work:

```
map.set({ name: 'bob' }, { food: 'cake' }) // error
```

In this case, `T` is inferred as `{name: string}` and `{food: 'cake'}` is not assignable to it.  So it's an error.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!